# PCI-Express: determining Max Read Request size

Tags: pci-express, system-info

Is there a way I can determine the current Max Read Request size of PCI-Express on a running Windows 7/8 system?

I have googled for some time now and have tried a number of programs that display system information like CPU-Z, HWiNFO64, etc., but to no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this configured in the BIOS? You can choose manual instead of automatic. I think currently the max is 4GB

Comment: Thanks for comment, @DaveRook. I don't have this option in BIOS - just the _Max Payload Size_, so that is why I'm asking whether I can somehow view this from a runnings OS. B/w the maximum is 4KiB ;)